# Powerhsell v2 crashing on launch

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-xp

I have PowerShell v2 installed on a windows XP SP3 machine and when I went to open PowerShell today it said:

```
The shell cannot be started. A failure occurred during initialization:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The event in the Powershell event log is:

```
Soruce: Powershell
Category: engine health
Event ID: 103

Settings: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

Details: 
ExceptionClass=NullReferenceException
ErrorCategory=
ErrorId=
ErrorMessage=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Severity=Error

SequenceNumber=

HostName=ConsoleHost
HostVersion=2.0
HostId=0fba5d45-885f-4f19-a354-4b390d5605bd
EngineVersion=2.0
RunspaceId=db9879d6-247a-40d7-9bfe-5bfd07a973f0
PipelineId=
CommandName=
CommandType=
ScriptName=
CommandPath=
CommandLine=
```

Any idea what would cause this? it seems to randomly start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/47f5cd95-c6ca-4dc9-b89c-4f0a28bf6a50/cant-launch-powershell-20-after-upgrade-from-10?forum=winserverpowershell) seems to suggest a missing registry key in your profile.

Excerpts from the discussion

> After analyzing the Process Monitor log again, I find this error occurred if the following Registry key was missing:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
> ```

Eventually the user rebuilt his local profile.

I have also seen success with people running the following command in powershell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Comment: Winner! Thank you so much! I needed to add 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment' along with a few entries in the Key. This seems to have fixed everything.

Comment: I was able to fix this by adding a user (not system) PATH environment variable; that created the required registry key without using regedit. My computer > properties > advanced system settings > environment variables > top half of window > new > PATH and C:\Windows\System32 > Save and OK out.